# Run configurations - Cannot connect to runtime process

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm atempting to run the node command `npm run dev` from the debugger in vscode.

My run config in `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "dev"
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
}]
```

My scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run build:live",
    "build:live": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -- ./app/*.ts"
}
```

But when i run the config i get this output:

```
npm --debug-brk=18538 run dev 
> discordbot@1.0.0 dev /home/olian04/Documents/Projects/Node/JavaScript/DiscordBot.js
> npm run build:live
> discordbot@1.0.0 build:live /home/olian04/Documents/Projects/Node/JavaScript/DiscordBot.js
> nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -- ./app/*.ts
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./app/index.ts`
```

And then this error:

```
Cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 10000 ms).
```

To me it looks as if it worked, but it still throws an error, and the code stops running when it does, why?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the `"port"` tag to the `"configurations"`. 
And the `--debug-brk` argument to the `"build:live"` node command.

Final configs:

```
"configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "dev"
    ],
    "port": 5858,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
}]
```

Final script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run build:live",
    "build:live": "nodemon --debug-brk=5858 --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -- ./app/*.ts"
}
```